# Step functions in state machine stopped transitions to the next state

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have been using state machines to generate pdfs. The problem is it was running fine but on 23 July this stopped working automatically. My first step gets invoked successfully but doesn't pass data to the next step and times out.

- Tried increasing the timeout it didn't work.
- Tried increasing quota for "StateTransition throttle token bucket size" it also didn't work
- Logs shows complete execution in the step but when sending data through callback to next step lambda gives a time out error.

Attaching my lambda function below.

```js
'use strict'
var db = require('database-layer');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.lambdaHandler =  (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);
    const bucket = process.env['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] || '';
    // This will allow us to freeze open connections to a database
    var data = event;
    var blogPayload = data.sqsPayload
    try {
        db.helpers.blogHelper.findHelper({_id: blogPayload._id, type: 'BLOG'}, (_, res) => {
            if(res.data){
                // create html file and send s3 uri
                let newHtmlContent = res.data.content +  embedSignatureInHtml(data.sqsPayload.signaturePayload);
                newHtmlContent = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body style="font-family: Dejavu Sans;">${newHtmlContent}</body></html>`
                var lambdaRequestId = context.awsRequestId;
                const output_filename = `html-file/${lambdaRequestId.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '')}.html`
                const s3PutParams = {
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: output_filename,
                    Body: newHtmlContent,
                    ContentType: 'text/html',
                    Metadata: { "x-amz-meta-requestId": lambdaRequestId }
                };
                s3.upload(s3PutParams, function(error, uploadData) {
                    if ( error ) {
                        console.error('s3:putObject failed!');
                        callback(null, {
                            'isAllowed': false,
                            'sqsQueData': data.sqsQueData
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(uploadData, ' data found and uploaded successfully.');
                    callback(null, {
                        'isAllowed': true,
                        'sqsQueData': data.sqsQueData,
                        'sqsPayload': data.sqsPayload,
                        'uploadedHtmlUri': process.env.APP_CDN + uploadData.Key,
                    });
                });


            } else {
                console.log('data not found', res)
                callback(null, {
                    'isAllowed': false,
                    'sqsQueData': data.sqsQueData
                });
            }
        });
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e.toString());
        callback(null, {
            'isAllowed': false,
            'sqsQueData': data.sqsQueData
        });
    }
}
```

This is the state machine definition that was working perfectly fine previously but now collapsed somehow.

```js
{
    "Comment": "A state machine that generates pdf and update the system",
    "StartAt": "Check Proposal",
    "States": {
        "Check Proposal": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${CheckProposalFunctionArn}",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0,
                    "BackoffRate": 1.5
                }
            ],
            "Next": "Generate Or Not?"
        },
        "Generate Or Not?": {
            "Type": "Choice",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "Variable": "$.isAllowed",
                    "BooleanEquals": true,
                    "Next": "Generate Pdf"
                }
            ],
            "Default": "Update SQS"
        },
        "Generate Pdf": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${GeneratePdfFunctionArn}",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                    "MaxAttempts": 1,
                    "BackoffRate": 1
                }
            ],
            "Next": "Update Or Not?"
        },
        "Update Or Not?": {
            "Type": "Choice",
            "Choices": [
                {
                    "Variable": "$.isAllowed",
                    "BooleanEquals": true,
                    "Next": "Update Pdf"
                }
            ],
            "Default": "Update SQS"
        },
        "Update Pdf": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${UpdatePdfUrlFunctionArn}",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                    "MaxAttempts": 1,
                    "BackoffRate": 1
                }
            ],
            "Next": "Update SQS"
        },
        "Update SQS": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${UpdateSQSFunctionArn}",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.TaskFailed"
                    ],
                    "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                    "MaxAttempts": 2,
                    "BackoffRate": 1
                }
            ],
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increase Lambda memory? Does this Lambda run over 15 minutes?